# Android 6 can not communicate with secured server using Self Sign Certificate

Tags: android, ssl, android-6.0-marshmallow, self-signed

I am unable to establish connection between Android 6 app and Secured Server where the server is using self signed certificate generated by Java (jdk 1.6) keytool command. Android 6 app is showing following error.

Excepton Log:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:429)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:257)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
05-23 17:21:03.498 3602-6487/issac.wise.pay I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
```

I am using the below code and it is working fine upto android 5.9 but it is not working with android 6(marshmallow); following link provides the code to communicate to ssl -

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
URL url = new URL("https://certs.cac.washington.edu/CAtest/");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
    (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

Can anybody please suggest how to resolve this? Is this any certificate generation problem or do I need to follow any new technique to communicate with server?

Comment: "it is working fine upto android 5.9" -- there is no Android 5.9. "following link provides the code to communicate to ssl" -- that is not your code, unless you are attempting to communicate with the University of Washington CA test server. Instead, that appears to be code that you copied from [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html). We cannot help you with *your* problem with *your* code unless we can see *your* code.

Comment: "Is this any certificate generation problem or do I need to follow any new technique to communicate with server ?" -- I cannot think of any changes in Android 6.0. Android's [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) offers new options here, but that is new to Android 7.0, though [I have backported it to Android 4.2](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity).

Answer (score 1):

Android 6 no longer accepts insecure connections, you should use a secure certificate or work around the issue by letting the app ignore insecure certificates (this creates heavy security issues and is not recommended at all).

**From Android Developers: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html**

> **Self-signed server certificate** The second case of SSLHandshakeException is due to a self-signed certificate, which means
>   the server is behaving as its own CA. This is similar to an unknown
>   certificate authority, so you can use the same approach from the
>   previous section.
>
> You can create your own TrustManager, this time trusting the server
>   certificate directly. This has all of the downsides discussed earlier
>   of tying your app directly to a certificate, but can be done securely.
>   However, you should be careful to make sure your self-signed
>   certificate has a reasonably strong key. As of 2012, a 2048-bit RSA
>   signature with an exponent of 65537 expiring yearly is acceptable.
>   When rotating keys, you should check for recommendations from an
>   authority (such as NIST) about what is acceptable